# How can I monitor live HDD statistics?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

I'm troubleshooting this issue where my HDD utilization hits 100% and the total amount of transfer taking place is 1-2 MBs at most. Thus I'm looking for a program with which I can troubleshoot this issue. The program should have enough detail to find out exactly which operations of which process are causing the issue. I'm on Windows 10

Edit: Another solution is if I could figure out a way to find out what's going on in the system processes, since they are the culprit here.
Attached a relevant screenshot. System and Antimalware executable are often the ones on the scene when this problem occurs:

[image: System and Antimalware executable are often the ones on the scene when this problem occurs]

Comment: If you're copying to/from a network location, then WireShark.  If it's from something else (eg, local disk, USB drive, CD-ROM, floppy, etc.), then please specify.  I'd start by disabling on-access anti-virus scanning to rule that out.  Also, please indicate how you are transferring the files (eg, Windows Explorer, xcopy, robocopy, PowerShell, FTP, WinSCP, HTTPS, etc.)

Comment: If you are willing to figure out how to use the filters, this can probably be solved using the [System Internals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).  Once you figure out the filters, you should be able to narrow down the problem fairly quickly.

Comment: @leeharvey1 the problem is coming from system processes. Nothing that is commissioned by me. Whenever this phenomenon takes place its just system, antimalware executable, accessing the HDD for 0.1Mbps each. I need a way to see what these two processes are upto. Or a software that would just point out the culprit behind  the full utilization.

Comment: My guess would be that the antimalware process is updating its definitions, then scanning running processes (and loaded modules) immediately after the update.

Comment: @AbhayPathak Could you please evaluate if my answer solves your problem or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Press Win + R on the keyboard to open the Run window;
> 2. In the Open field type "resmon";
> 3. Press Enter on the keyboard (or click OK);
> 4. Go to the "Disk" tab;
> 5. Gather the information you need from it.

Reference: [11 ways to start Resource Monitor in Windows: #7. Use the Run window (all Windows versions)](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/start-resource-monitor-windows/)